# SFP Bidi with Different Downstream to Upstream Wavelength is working?

Tags: sfp, optical

After reading some documents available about concepts of BiDi SFPs. There should be a pair sfp upstream dan downstream to make a link established. when sfp U on wavelength 1310nm-Tx/1490nm-Rx should be paired to sfp D with wavelength 1490nm-Tx/1310nm-Rx.

In my case, on the connection between 2 buildings 2km apart, I have sfp BiDi U from Fs.com with wavelength of 1310nm-Tx/1490nm-Rx plugged to switch cisco, and on the orher side, I have sfp BiDi D from Ubiquiti with wavelength of 1550nm-Tx/1310-Rx plugged to switch Unifi. The link was connected with attenuation of -6dB of Tx and -7dB on Rx

> IDBAHO001#show interfaces gigabitEthernet 1/0/28 transceiver
>
> ```
>                                         Optical   Optical
>        Port       Temperature  Voltage  Tx Power  Rx Power 
>                   (Celsius)    (Volts)  (dBm)     (dBm)
>        ---------  -----------  -------  --------  -------- 
>        Gi1/0/28     32.6       3.22      -6.0      -7.0
> ```

. Why is it connected though? Is it normal?
And what could possibly happened to the Tx wavelength that doesn't match from the downstream side to the upstream?

I was just curious, As I don't experience any inconvenience on end point activity.

Comment: The better question: is it passing traffic without error? As Zak has answered, (cheap) optics aren't pinpoint accurate. For example, I have MM (850nm) converter that will "link" with SM (1310nm) LED SFP. It won't reliably pass traffic, but it does link. (the expensive SM SFP that uses a laser doesn't work -- that side shows no link.)

Answer (score 1):

Neither emission nor detection are only happening on a single wavelength. Rather, there's a central wavelength and a bell-shaped curve around that.[*1] Not-so-close matching the wavelengths significantly increases attenuation and reduces reach but still works within that limitations. Depending on the exact transceiver used, a mismatch may or may not

2 km isn't much for single-mode fiber, so you might not really be seeing much consequence from the wavelength mismatch. However, the width of the wavelength distribution may vary with the exact transceiver at hand (and its laser and detection technology) - if you need to replace one of the SFP modules in the future, the connection might get much worse. I'd document the problem well and correct the wavelength mismatch on occasion.

[*1] For 1000BASE-BX10, IEEE 802.3 tables 59-6 & 59-7 define an 'operating' window of 20 nm for transmitter and receiver wavelengths in the D→U direction (1480-1500 nm). Outside of that window, attenuation *may* decrease sharply when mismatching wavelengths.